# Unity UI, how to hide on play

Tags: unity

I have created a menu on Unity using the built in UI components,I can't create this on a seperate scene because I used the toggle button, which basically when you click it, it spawns a specific object (I have 4 of these toggle buttons). I have completed making the menu on the my current scene. My problem is that when I start on runtime,  the menu appears in front of the first person character controller, and when I move the mouse to click the toggle, the camera controller follows the mouse movement. How do I fix this? Also when I click all of the toggle buttons, I want the UI to dissapear, so it isn't shown when I am playing the game because atm when I click the toggle buttons, the actual buttons stay on the screen whilst I am navigating around the scene, is there any way to make this invisible?

Comment: I suggest reading the UI documentation: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html

Comment: @ZEKE That comment is really not helpful. Please at least have the courtesy link to the specific chapter of the UI documentation which is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in several different games with the [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) approach.

Your game has at least two different UI states in which it reacts differently to user input:

- the "in menu" state
- the "playing in first person" state.

It might have even more states you didn't mention or aren't aware yet that you will need them. For example what almost every game needs once in a while is a null-state in which most input is ignored.

Implement each of these different input-states as a separate MonoBehaviour.

Create another script `InputStateManager` which references all input-states in the scene and provides methods to switch between them. Such a state switch is performed by setting `enabled = true` on the state you request and `enabled = false` on all others. The `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` methods of your input states can also take care of activating and deactivating any UI objects which should only be visible while in that state (like the canvas of your menu).

The advantage of this method is that you achieve loose coupling between your different input states and can easily add a new one without touching the code of the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you what I did.

I had a `bool` on a camera scripts that says whether the camera should rotate or not, so I called it `bool shouldRotateCamera = true;`

And when you pop the menu, whether it's by using <kbd>Esc</kbd> or any other way, you can change that value in camera script to `this.shouldRotateCamera = false;`

In the update method of camera script always check `if (shouldRotate)`. The camera should rotate if so.

Regarding the UI, you can technically enable/disable it.

If there are any questions, feel free to ask.